# NSString and no UTF-8 symbols

Tags: iphone, objective-c, utf-8, nsstring

For some of you (I'm sure) this question is quite simple to answer, but I have some difficulties in understanding how to solve the problem.

I have a .txt file containing a table like this:

" 236
? 26
x00EE 16

As you probably understood the left column lists symbols and the right one lists some code of the, I defined in my app.

And... you probably understood that, within symbols, there are some "strange". The 0x00EE should be the "å" (a with a ring above).

Unfortunately I can't control the left column, i.e. it comes from another software. Making some experiments I found that:

```
NSLog( @"\x00ee" );
```

for example produces a waring telling the hte code does not belong to the UTF-8 range.

So I was wandering how to convert the NSString @"\x00ee" (that I read from file, so is a string composed of 6 chars) to the unique unicode letter "å" (a with a ring above).

Can anyone help me?

Thanks...

Comment: @Filip Unlikely, 0x00ee is not a UTF-8 code point.

Comment: Does this answer your question?
[How to convert a string of hex codes into a UTF-8 character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78022259)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input string contains only ASCII characters then you can use the fact that
`NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding` decodes `\uNNNN` to the corresponding Unicode character:

```
NSString *s = @"\\x00ee"; // from your text file
NSString *s1 = [s stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\x" withString:@"\\u"];
NSData *d = [s1 dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *s2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:d encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog (@"%@", s2);
```

Output: `î`, which is U+00EE (LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH CIRCUMFLEX).

(Remark: `å` is U+00E5, not U+00EE).

Answer (score 2):

You need to find out what character set encoding was used. 0xEE is unicode for î.  In Unicode, å is E5.  This is encoded in UTF-8 as the sequence 0xC3 0xA5.  The following does the trick for me:

```
    NSLog(@"\xc3\xa5");
```

Comment: Also this answer works. Because I can't upgrade two answers to "best answer" status, I raised the interest of your reply :-)